# Unable to run Mean Application on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, mean-stack

I have tried many times to create an app but unable to run.
**Command: gulp**

this error every single time

```html
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[19:59:20] [nodemon] watching 174 files
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is probably running in the background or some other process maybe bound to the port,

try following command,

`netstat -tulpn`

get the pid of the process bound to the port and kill it using

```
kill <pid>
```

try the first command again if it's still there try,

```
kill -KILL <pid>
```

And try running again